# Oozie server shared library is of the wrong type for its MapReduce service dependency

Tags: hadoop-yarn, oozie, cloudera-cdh

When trying run an Oozie workflow via the `oozie` CLI on CDH 5.5.1, I immediately get the error:

> The Oozie server shared library is of the wrong type for its MapReduce
>   service dependency

I've googled the error message, and get zero results.

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Oozie configuration had been changed from MapReduce to YARN in Cloudera Manager, for consistency with another cluster (on which this Oozie job runs fine).

However, Cloudera Manager doesn't mention that you also need to redeploy the Oozie ShareLib to match your current MapReduce service, if you [switch between MapReduce and YARN](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cm_mc_mr_and_yarn.html#concept_knt_qxk_gp). This is described in the [Managing Oozie documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/admin_oozie_sharelib.html):

> When you upgrade CDH or switch between MapReduce and YARN computation
>   frameworks,  redeploy the Oozie ShareLib as follows:

1. Go to the Oozie service.
2. Select Actions > Stop.
3. Select Actions > Install Oozie ShareLib.
4. Select Actions > Start.